# regex last character of a WORD

Tags: regex, string

I'm attempting to match the last character in a WORD.

A WORD is a sequence of non-whitespace characters
'[^\n\r\t\f ]', or an empty line matching ^$.

The expression I made to do this is: 
"[^ \n\t\r\f]\(?:[ \$\n\t\r\f]\)"

The regex matches a non-whitespace character that follows a whitespace character or the end of the line.

But I don't know how to stop it from excluding the following whitespace character from the result and why it doesn't seem to capture a character preceding the end of the line.

Using the string "Hi World!", I would expect: the "i" and "!" to be captured.

Instead I get: "i ".

What steps can I take to solve this problem?

Comment: Question: how do you expect to match the empty line? What's the last character of that?

Comment: What flavor regex are you using? Are capture groups a thing for you, or does it have to be an all-or-nothing kind of deal?

Comment: It could go to the start of the empty line or it could just skip empty lines. I am not super concerned about that behavior. Capture groups are a thing for me. I'm using elisp regex flavor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"Word" that is a sequence of non-whitespace characters scenario**

Note that a non-capturing group `(?:...)` in `[^ \n\t\r\f](?:[ \$\n\t\r\f])` still matches (consumes) the whitespace char (thus, it becomes a part of the match) and it does not match at the end of the string as the `$` symbol is not a string end anchor inside a character class, it is parsed as a literal `$` symbol.

You may use

```
\S(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a1JZOr/2)

The `\S` matches a non-whitespace char that is not followed with a non-whitespace char (due to the `(?!\S)` negative lookahead).

**General "word" case**

If a word consists of just letters, digits and underscores, that is, if it is matched with `\w+`, you may simply use

```
\w\b
```

Here, `\w` matches a "word" char, and the word boundary asserts there is no word char right after.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a1JZOr/21).

Comment: How can I match a character and replace when present as the last character on any word?

Comment: I actually need this [https://regex101.com/r/cL0gU8/7] but instead of the first character this should be last.

Comment: @Jnanaranjan Then use `([a-zA-Z"])(?!\S)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cL0gU8/8)

Answer (score -1):

In Word text, if I want to highlight the last a in para. I search for all the words that have [space][para][space] to make sure I only have the word I want, then when it is found it should be highlighted.
Next, I search for the last [a ] space added, in the selection and I will get only the last [a] and I will highlight it or color it differently.

Comment: Are you under the impression that OP is talking about the office program Word?